Why did the caching issue with GET requests resolve on Vercel without needing "cache": "no-store" in Next.js?
A few months ago, I built a basic CRUD application with Next.js and deployed it on Vercel. Initially, I ran into a caching issue with my GET APIs. When I added new data and refreshed the page, the old data would still display, and the new entries wouldn’t show up right away. After some research, I found that adding
cache: 'no-store'

when calling the API could prevent this caching issue, and it worked perfectly at the time.
However, I recently noticed that the caching issue no longer exists on Vercel, even if I don’t include
cache: 'no-store' 

in my API requests. Now, the latest data appears immediately after refreshes, without any caching issues.
I'm curious—did this happen due to a recent update in Next.js or Vercel? Is there a specific reason why the GET request caching behavior seems to have changed?
Any insights into why this issue resolved itself would be really helpful.

Assuming that you've updated to Next 15, caching is no longer enabled by default.
https://nextjs.org/blog/next-15#get-route-handlers-are-no-longer-cached-by-default
